# Java : Unable to delete files using FileUtils.deleteQuietly,ForceDelete,FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete;

Tags: java, file, apache-commons

I use `FileUtils.deleteQuietly()` method to delete files after copying to some other places.But it is not deleting the file and the files are staying in the same path.

```
    File folder = new File(Marker_Source_path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if(folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory() && folder.list().length>0)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i<listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {       
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
            {
                String Filename= listOfFiles[i].getName();
                String Filename_path=listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                File File_with_path=new File(Filename_path);
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(File_with_path, destinationDir2_TITLE_MM);
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(File_with_path, destinationDir3_PUB_TYPE);
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(File_with_path, destinationDir4_ISSUE_FREQ);
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(File_with_path, destinationDir4_VOL_ISSUE);
 System.out.println("Marker File : " + Filename + " Moved to destination Dir : "+ destinationDir2_TITLE_MM.getAbsolutePath() + " 
           Successfully...");
         Boolean check_del=FileUtils.deleteQuietly(File_with_path);
              System.out.println("Is File deleted : "+check_del);
            }
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Markers to Copy....");
    }
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. As-is, the code snippet is nigh unreadable.

Comment: `FileUtils.deleteQuietly` will suppress all exceptions. You can check the return value (true/false) if anything was deleted. If you are interested in what exactly did not work, don't use "quietly", but look at the exception you get with the normal "delete" method.

Comment: @ thilo : It gives the Boolean result False of file Deleting.kindly help me to identify what is wrong exactly.

Comment: @Thilo : Methods : FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(File_with_path); and FileUtils.ForceDelete(File_with_path); Throws IOException.Kindly help.

Comment: @CptBartender : I hope it is readable now and sorry for the poor formatting.Kindly help ,Thank you

Comment: What does the IOException say?

Comment: @ Thilo : Found the Solution.It throws Access denied exception due to the permission.I fixed at last.Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

- This is Happened due to the File permission issue.
- After Giving permission it works fine and no issue with the above code.

Comment: can u share that ... i am facing the same issue while deleting the file...